# Default error messages in grails

Tags: grails, message, defaults

I want to know where Grails sets default error messages. For example I've got this one in my message.properties file. When I try to save data with wrong value, this message appears. But I can't understand where (in code) he sets this message.

```
default.invalid.min.message=Property {0} with value {2} is less than minimum value {3}
```

Answer (score 2):

Grails uses this message automatically when a property doesn't pass `min` constraint. You can override this message and edit your messages.properties file or you can create customised messages for your classes. Check out the documentation here: [min constraint](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/min.html), the last sentence is `Error Code: className.propertyName.min.notmet`. So for a class Person and property age description for unmet min constraint your should use in your messages.properites:

```
person.age.min.notmet=Sorry, you're too young!
```

Comment: Ok, I know that I can set custom error messages. My problem is another, I have  2 domain classes Form and FormItem, Form has many FormItem. I try to save Form with wrong FormItem values, and the result is duplicated error messages. Every error message printed twice. Now I want to understand where he sets these messages and why twice ? Other messages that are not connected with FormItem fields printed fine only one time.

Comment: @emilan maybe you're affected with this bug: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8924 ?